# Rotate and scale the POSITION of several sprites based on a center point?

Tags: rotation, position, scale, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm looking for some guidance as I haven't found documentation or threads regarding the topic. I have numerous spritenodes in my scene that a user can drag around at will.
Additionally, I need the user to be able to select multiple sprites and

- rotate the positions of the selected sprites based on a center point
  calculated based on which sprites were selected (ie. if the sprites
  that were selected are already in a circle formation, and the user
  rotates the formation, each sprite's position should rotate and
  mainain the circle.
- scale the positions of the selected sprites, again, based on a center
  point calculated based on which sprites were selected (ie. if the
  selected sprites are in a circle formation and the user scales the
  formation, the circle should get bigger or smaller accordingly

There will be other events I'll need to handle, but this should get me started. I am already maintaining which sprites are selected and changing their positions (single sprites and multiple sprites). I'm at a loss as to how to rotate and scale their positions.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

This is a different approach, but what you could do is :

1. Create a container SKNode
2. create a SKNode , call it spriteGroup or something like that, and add any sprites you want to be connected in the way you described to that node.
3. Add the spriteGroup to the containerNode.
4. Center the spriteGroup on the 0,0 location of the container node.  For example if the spriteGroup's width is 100 and it's height is 100 , you'd want it's position to be -50,-50.

Now you can rotate/scale/move the container and achieve the desired functionality.

Here's an example :

```
SKNode *container = [[SKNode alloc]init];
SKNode *group = [[SKNode alloc]init];

for (int index = 0;index < 4;index++)
{
    SKSpriteNode *sprite = [[SKSpriteNode alloc]initWithImageNamed:@"santa.png"];
    sprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    sprite.position = CGPointMake(index * 100, 0);
    [group addChild:sprite];
}

CGRect groupRect = [group calculateAccumulatedFrame];
group.position = CGPointMake(-groupRect.size.width/2, -groupRect.size.height/2);

[container addChild:group];
[self addChild:container];

container.position = CGPointMake(512, 384);
container.xScale = .5;
container.yScale = .5;

container.zRotation = 45 * M_PI /180;
```