# Rotation of SKSpriteNode grouped with its shadow

Tags: ios, rotation, sprite-kit, shadow, skspritenode

I am trying to perform some actions on a SKSpriteNode grouped with its shadow in a SKNode. Translation works correctly, but rotation is still a problem.

I implemented adding shadow as follows:

```
- (SKNode *) addShadow:(NSString *) nodeName At:(CGPoint) pos
{
    float halfWdth = self.frame.size.width / 2.f;
    float halfHght = self.frame.size.height / 2.f;

    SKEffectNode *shadowEffect = [[SKEffectNode alloc] init];
    shadowEffect.shouldEnableEffects = YES;

    SKNode *shadowNode = [[SKNode alloc] init];

    SKSpriteNode *shadow = [self copy];
    shadow.color = [SKColor blackColor];
    shadow.colorBlendFactor = 0.9;
    shadow.blendMode = SKBlendModeAlpha;
    [shadow setAlpha:0.7];
    shadowEffect.filter = [self blurFilter];
    shadow.position = CGPointMake(halfWdth + SHADOW_DELTA, halfHght);
    shadow.zPosition = -10;
    shadowEffect.name = @"shadow";
    shadowEffect.blendMode = SKBlendModeAlpha;
    [shadowEffect addChild:shadow];

    self.zPosition = 3;
    self.position = CGPointMake(halfWdth, halfHght + SHADOW_DELTA);

    [shadowNode addChild:shadowEffect];
    [shadowNode addChild:self];

    shadowNode.name = nodeName;
    shadowNode.position = pos;
    shadowNode.zPosition = 3;

    SKNode *container = [[SKNode alloc] init];
    container.name = nodeName;

    CGRect groupRect = [shadowNode calculateAccumulatedFrame];
    halfWdth = groupRect.size.width / 2.f;
    halfHght = groupRect.size.height / 2.f;

    shadowNode.position = CGPointMake(-halfWdth, -halfHght);

   [container addChild:shadowNode];
   container.position = CGPointMake(pos.x + halfWdth, pos.y + halfHght);

   return (container);
```

}

I found the link [Rotate and scale the POSITION of several sprites based on a center point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964896/rotate-and-scale-the-position-of-several-sprites-based-on-a-center-point). However, I could not solve my problem.

I used the following code segments for translation and rotation;

Translation:

```
 SKAction *moveAction = [SKAction moveBy:CGVectorMake(-2.f, mMoveY) duration:0.2f];

 [paper runAction:moveAction completion:
 ^{
      [self processHelp:@"help3];     
  }];
```

Rotation:

```
 SKAction *rotateAction = [SKAction rotateByAngle:0.75f * M_PI duration:0.4f];
[mainNode runAction:rotateAction];
```

I would be glad if someone can guide me.

Regards,

Neslisah.

Comment: Please add code which you are using to rotate the sprite. Also add the code which you use to translate the node.

Comment: I editted my question with translation and rotation, thanks.

Comment: What seems to be the problem?